# Determine |S|, where S = {gcd(n, 210) | n ∈ Z}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone explain how this question is supposed to be done? This is a first year discrete math question.

Comment: gcd(n,210) must of course divide 210. but also any divisor of 210 can be the gcd, by just taking the gcd of it with 210, say.

Comment: Perhaps it would clarify matters for you if you started with a smaller number.  Say, $10$ instead of $210$.

Comment: @lulu That would help. Although I still do not know what to do even if its 10 instead of 210.

Comment: For $10$, just take all the numbers between $0$ and $10$, and each time find the gcd. Then go on to the numbers between $10$ and $20$. If you don’t see a pattern, go on to the next decade. Please don’t be afraid of pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will work out two smaller examples as suggested by lulu in the comments, and leave it to you to do the larger case.

We want to find all possible values of $d=\gcd(n,10)$ where $n$ runs through all integers. Now, by definition, the greatest common divisor must at least be a common divisor, so in particular $d\mid 10$. By definition again $d$ is positive. What this means is that there are only four possible values: $d=1,2,5,10$, since these are all the divisors of $10$. Now, we can see that each of these values are attainable, since choosing $n=1,2,5,10$ respectively will give us the desired value of $d$. Therefore, the value of $|S|$ is just the number of divisors of $10$, which turns out to be $4$.

As another example, suppose we were working with $9$ instead of $10$. Then again $d=\gcd(n,9)$ divides $9$, so it can only be $1,3,9$. But each of these are attainable because we can take $n=1,3,9$ respectively. So $|S|$ is exactly the number of divisors of $9$, which is $3$.

Can you generalise this to larger numbers? If the numbers get as big as $210$, it might get tedious to list out all its factors manually, so it probably makes more sense to have a nice way of counting. If you have not learnt the connection between number of factors and prime factorisation before, you can look [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/factors/) for an explanation.